# unable to import libraries in eclipse for google places api project

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I am developing an application where i need to find nearest petrol stations using google places api. But the problem is i am unable to import the libraries. here are the lines where i am getting errors.

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
```

Comment: _i am getting errors_ won't tell us what is the error. Please be more specific and state what errors you are getting.

Comment: please read my question again!! i have mentioned in the beginning itself!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list) **add this to your android application's build path** via **Add Jar** or Add **External Jar**.

```
Android Application -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add jars.. or Add External Jars..
```

Comment: `GoogleHeaders` Not found

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
Android Application -> Properties -> Android ->select Google APIS(2.2 or any)-> Apply-> ok.
Then Right Click on your project -> Refresh.
```

i am not sure ,but i think it shoud work.

Comment: while creating this project i had chosen google API only.. but still i have this problem